# Google Chart API - Google Finance Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I've been trying to create a chart that looks similar to [Google's Finance Charts](http://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3aC).  I've gotten almost everything I want with the [Annotated Time Line Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#annotated_time_line), except I can't seem to figure out how to incorporate the volume information they have at the bottom of the charts.  I was wondering if anybody knew how to do this or where to look, I've been all around their API but can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Someone, a real live person - not on Stack, suggested this: http://www.humblesoftware.com/finance/index

Going with that as the answer.

Comment: This might be good API. But could not even visible graph in my browser as integrated provided code. any basic requirements ?

Comment: @Liladhar it's been a while, but looking at their docs it looks like it requires Prototype 1.6.1+ and Flotr 2.0 http://www.humblesoftware.com/finance/documentation

Comment: dint say anything about the licence, do you know anything about it?

Answer (score 5):

IMO this chart looks nearly identical to the original Google Finance chart and is also maintained by Google. It's also a part of the Google charts library wich is pretty awesome by itself.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline

Answer (score 3):

Try using this clone instead?

http://code.google.com/p/time-series-graph/

The Annotated Time Line Chart doesn't include the bar graphing facility along the bottom which Google Finance has - I imagine they have an internal API set that isn't exposed to the external world.

Comment: Ended up going with this: http://www.humblesoftware.com/finance/index which is more what I was looking for.  +1 for a good suggestion though.